# get all youtube video from a channel (only 25 videos are shown) asp.net

Tags: asp.net, video, youtube

I have to get all the videos from a youtube channel. I have used following code but it is returning only top 25 videos. I need all the uploaded videos. Please help me regarding this.

```
 public class YoutubeVideoHelper
{
    const string YOUTUBE_CHANNEL = "UPGovtOfficial";
    const string YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY = "My Developer key";

   public static DataTable GetVideos()
   {
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       dt.Columns.Add("Title");
       dt.Columns.Add("VideoId");
       YouTubeRequestSettings settings =
       new YouTubeRequestSettings(YOUTUBE_CHANNEL, YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY);
       YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
       string feedUrl = String.Format
       ("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{0}/uploads?orderby=published&max-result=100", 
    YOUTUBE_CHANNEL);
       Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedUrl));

       foreach (var video in videoFeed.Entries)
       {
           DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
           dr["Title"] = video.Title;
           dr["VideoId"] = video.VideoId;
           dt.Rows.Add(dr);
       }

       return dt;

   }
}
```

Comment: Check this: http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn-history/r890/docs/folder54/AllMembers_T_Google_GData_Client_RequestSettings.htm

Comment: I have added one more element in querystring that is PageSize=100. but no success.

Comment: Set AutoPaging to true and Maximum and PageSize to 100 in YouTubeRequestSettings

Comment: ok. I'll add samething as answer. Please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Set `AutoPaging` to `true` and specify `Maximum`,`PageSize` properties values to required value (100) of `YouTubeRequestSettings` object.

Below is the link for more details:

http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn-history/r890/docs/folder54/AllMembers_T_Google_GData_Client_RequestSettings.htm